# CSS @media query for 1920x1080 at 125% zoom

Tags: html, css, media-queries

so I kind of have a weird problem. I have made a website, styled it and everything based on 1920x1080 at 100% zoom (of the device's zoom idk if you get what I'm saying I mean the Windows zoom in screen settings) and now I want, using the @media query, to style it for devices that are at 1920x1080 at 125% zoom (again of the device's zoom). Can someone help me?

I tried doing this:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (min-zoom: 125%){/*my styles*/}
```

but it didn't exactly work. It does now look normal on 1920x1080 at 125% zoom but not at 100%.
Can someone help me?

Comment: When it asks for more text describing the problem, please add more, **different** text describing the problem, not the exact same text copied and pasted. A good thing to do in your case would be example HTML and CSS that shows the problem and what is meant by "not at 100%".

Comment: It's possible that the underlying issue may be with how some of your CSS is set up/written, you may be using a mix of different units to size your elements and text (e.g. `em`, `rem`, `px`, there are [many different units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)). If you share a little more of your code (either here or in a code sandbox) showing the issue, the community may be able to offer better help and explanations